# Почему equals считает объекты одного и того же класса не идентичными?

Tags: java

Увидел вот такой пример, который описан:
Сообщает вам считаются ли два объекта идентичными.

```
Cat c = new Cat();
Dog d = new Dog();

if (c.equals(d)) {
    System.out.println("Perfect");
} else {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

Это пример я понимаю почему выдает -  `"Error"`, но почему этот пример выдает тоже `"Error"`? Ведь объекты одного и того же класса.

```
            Cat c = new Cat();
            Cat d = new Cat();

            if (c.equals(d)) {
                System.out.println("Perfect");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
```

1. Почему второй вариант выдает `"Error"`?
2. И что такое идентичность?

Comment: Потому что это разные объекты. Представьте, что вы поймали двух котов на улице - это будут разные объекты одного класса. Чтобы объекты сравнивались по каким-то параметрам (например, пол порода, окраска и т.д.), нужно переопределить метод equals их класса так, чтобы проверялось равенство по этим параметрам.

Answer (score 1):

По дефолту берется реализация Object#equals, которая сравнивает reference каждого из них (адрес в памяти, если я не ошибаюсь). Так как эти объекты разные (то есть разные адреса в памяти) - equals возвращает false.

Можно переопределить equals метод для сравнивания не по reference, а по вашим собственным желаниям (значение полей, например). Но, как обычно делают при переопределении этого метода, то это сравнивают одинаковые ли типы (Cat и Dog). Если вы сделаете по канонам (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185937/overriding-the-java-equals-method-not-working), то equals здесь будет все равно возвращать false

Answer (score 1):

Метод `equals` проверяет идентичность ссылки одного экземпляра класса другому. 
В вашем случае вы создаете два экземпляра с двумя разными ссылками:

```
Cat c = new Cat();
Cat d = new Cat();
```

Если необходимо проверить именно на идентичность одному классу, тогда можете получить названия классов методом `getClass()` и уже их сравнить методом `equals()`:

```
if (c.getClass().equals(d.getClass())) {
    System.out.println("Perfect");
} else {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

Как вариант можно еще воспользоваться оператором `instanceof`, им мы сможем проверить является ли класс `Cat` "общим предком":

```
if ((c instanceof Cat) && (d instanceof Cat)) {
    System.out.println("Perfect");
} else {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Метод equals наследуется от класса Object. Реализация его - это по сути сравнивание ссылок (==) поэтому, так как вы сравниваете два разных объекта, метод возвращает false.
2. Идентичность объектов - это сравнение "содержимого" внутри экземпляров класса, т.е. помимо проверки что объекты одного класса, проверяются еще их поля. Например:

```
public class Dog {

    private String name;

    public Dog() {
    }

    public Dog(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true; //проверка, вдруг это один и тот же экземпляр
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false; //проверка что другой объект не null и не другого класса
        Dog dog = (Dog) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, dog.name); //проверка, что имена собак совпадают т.е. экземпляры идентичны
    }
}
```

теперь при создании экземпляров без изменения внутренних полей, они будут идентичны:

```
        Dog dogA = new Dog();
        Dog dogB = new Dog();
        Dog dogC = new Dog("Polkan");
        Dog dogD = new Dog("Polkan");

        dogA.equals(dogA);//true - это один и тот же экземпляр, поэтому идентичен сам себе
        dogA.equals(dogB);//true - оба экземпляра не содержат имени и идентичны
        dogA.equals(dogC);//false - имена отличаются, не идентичны
        dogC.equals(dogD);//true - имена одинаковые, идентичны
```